# Run one stored procedure within another stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named `[usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList]` that takes two arguments `@MovieID INT, @UserName Nvarchar(250)` and returns data something like this

```
Exec usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList @MovieID, @UserName

IsPaidUser   | IsSubscribeUser
   0                 0
```

Now in my another stored procedure I have something like

```
DECLARE @tblTemp1 TABLE (
        MovieID INT
        ,IsPaidUser BIT
        ,IsSubscribeUser BIT
        )
```

Here I know `@MovieID` value

Now I need to do something like

```
INSERT INTO @tblTemp1
SELECT @MovieID (EXEC [usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList] @MovieID,@userName )
```

Which is obviously not correct.

Help me to do so...Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take output in another variable and then use it:

```
 DECLARE @Movieid int
 EXEC @Movieid = [usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList] @MovieID,@userName
```

Here assumptions are:
1. You have @MovieID and @userName with you.
2. Your stored proc usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList is returning proper value.

Comment: Yes I know the proper value of MovieID and UserName. EXEC [usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList] @MovieID,@UserName will return two value.I have to insert thosE value in another table along with MovieID

Comment: You can return only one value from stored procedure. If you want more, then you have to use the OUT parameter.So, modify your stored proc usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList and add two out parameters. Calling it from your stored procedure will be same, but you need to pass the out parameters as well in "Exec" command.

Comment: If my table would be  `DECLARE @tblTemp2 TABLE ( 
  IsPaidUser BIT
  ,IsSubscribeUser BIT
  )` then i can easily insert using  `INSERT INTO @tblTemp2
EXEC [usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList] @MovieID,@userName ` But I have one more field to insert. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return `MovieID` in the output of stored procedure `usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList` since you know it there also. Then you can use simple insert in another stored procedure like :

```
INSERT INTO @tblTemp1
EXEC [usp_Movie_GetUserPaidList] @MovieID,@userName
```